# How to send SMS to a number stored in a JSON file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio

I need to send SMS (by Twilio) to defined phone numbers, which are saved in the *phone.json* file when the submit button will be clicked.

I am using node.js

How am I going to do this?

This is how my *phone.json* looks:

```
[
 {"Nombre": "Nombre1" ,
   "Numero": "+34...."
  },

 {"Nombre": "Nombre2",
  "Numero": "+34..."
 }
]
```

In SMS.js I would create a function like this:

```
function submit() {
  client.messages 
    .create({
      body: "content", 
      from: "+....", 
        to: ""}) //this number should come from phone.json
    .then(message => console.log(message.sid));
}
```

This is how my index.js looks:

```
const http =require('http');
const express = require('express');
const MessagingResponse = require('twilio').twiml.MessagingResponse;
const { fstat } = require('fs');
const { response } = require('express');
const info = require("./database.json"); 
const app = express();
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.listen(8000, console.log(`Server running at http://localhost:8000`));
```

I would be very happy about every suggestion.

Comment: What is the problem? Errors? If so please post the console log too

Comment: Go and check Twilio docs

Comment: @mplungjan the "problem" is, that I do not know, how to get the phone number from the phone.jason file.. I guess I need to add this somehow in the sms.js ...but am not really sure how...

Comment: @Masood of course, I have checked this already...but couldn't find docs to my specific issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to do this server-side in Node.js, then you need `fs` to read the JSON and then you just loop over it in your `submit()` like this:

```
import fs from "fs";  // CommonJS syntax: const fs = require("fs");
phone_numbers = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("phone.json", "utf8"));
phone_numbers.forEach(function(item, index) {
  console.log(item, index);
  client.messages 
    .create({
      body: "content", 
      from: "+....", 
      to: item["Numero"],
    })
    .then(message => console.log(message.sid));
});
```

Comment: That's great. Thank you @yvesonline !  Yes I want to do this on server-side in Node.js  So than do I still need the function in SMS.js? Or I can just handle it trough index.js (server) ?

Comment: I don't know your code and how you structured it. If you want to encapsulate it in a separate function that's up to you. Just make sure you wire it to the part when the user performs an action. You can test it first in the Node.js console, remember you also need to instantiate the `client` object like this: `const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);`

Comment: Thank you @yvesonline. I got it. I have one more question for my understanding...Now I get all data from the phone.json . But what is, if I only want the Number of the Name, which has been entered in html before e.g. "Nombre1" ?  Can I do there some loop to find the correct number? And yes, what do I need to consider ? Thank you